# Cannot delete cluster, Peering does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I went to delete a GKE cluster and after some time it gave me the error:

```
Google Compute Engine: There is no peering (gke-16b473dddf3526a46ffd-76d2-f9f0-peer) 
for the network (GLOBAL:global/PROJECT:redacted/NETWORK:dev).
```

Now the cluster is stuck. It can't be deleted and I can't create a new one with the same name. I can't recreate the peering either as I do not know what the project is for the peer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a coincidence, the same happened to me today and could not find any information about it except the question.

I solved the problem via this hacky way though:

1. Create a new VPC in your project. Just name it test or something.
2. Create a new pairing between the VPC of your cluster and this new VPC, using the name from the error message. (gke-16b473dddf3526a46ffd-76d2-f9f0-peer in your case)
3. Now delete the cluster: It'll delete this peering you just created along with the cluster.
4. Delete the VPC you created.

Comment: I didn't think of creating a random VPC for the peering. That was genius!